# Similarties and Preserving the characteristic polynomial and rank of a nilpotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, similar-matrices

Let $M_n$ be the algebra of all complex $n \times n$ matrices.
The theorem states that

> Let $\phi : M_n \to M_n$ be a surjective mapping satisfying
> $\det(A+\lambda B)=\det(\phi(A)+\lambda\phi(B)),\quad A,B \in M_n, \lambda \in \mathbb{C}.$\
> Then there exist $M,N \in M_n$ with $\det(MN)=1$ such that either
> $\phi(A) = MAN, \; A \in M_n \quad \text{or} \quad
> \phi(A) = MA^{T}N, \; A \in M_n.$

The proof is pretty long, but I've done proving that $\phi$ is now bijective, rank$(\phi(A))$=rank$(A)$, and the characteristic polynomial of $\phi(A)$ and $A$ are same. But there is another statement says that,

> Let us denote by $N ∈ M_n$ the matrix with 1’s above the main diagonal and zeroes elsewhere, $N = E_{12} + E_{23} +···+ E_{n−1,n}$. Since $\phi$ preserves the characteristic
> polynomial and rank, $\phi(N)$ must be similar to $N$.

The question is, is it necessary for only two conditions to claim that $\phi(N)$ is similar to $N$? Is there any special case for nilpotent matrices?

Here is the reference, [here](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271586/1-s2.0-S0024379500X03345/1-s2.0-S002437950100578X/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEC4aCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIFS9%2BAEX0CXjiIXvY7sxm63baRUDn5oPf%2F2ZC8qunyV6AiEAgaU9qOsWqVfBS%2BlL17svKPc%2BRIrhwOK653GaxO8KN84qvAUI1%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDMyW8vyLprQ5iG5KQSqQBVVPbeB%2BRNvmNfD1r6igMDzsZ%2FkO%2B%2B%2FepsqQJhkaxlVq5E%2BuFc1wWxZMciaATdH0nTecvuYmqrQXz486YTmW1bNAijsZx%2BD8DJ9yW3AAwdziu1i6fQlIPC%2FDgQ8U7Ih3%2F69KG0vmRIo34JVQwRil5PgwAfkyxSM70owDU4rP6D4u9JFWo1%2BqCj0%2FgwfuDOCfsCvhOAu8J5ESiSpVhQ7PJTCMWiCJFxW91VHeUvz9X7uoFDjvibwWOti0l723%2FYlbWBXnFrtB%2FGKjUbqj7ZcAdaks%2FNyrFSBRroIU53koGzY3xmE7rE0dSBpVb73w%2B%2FWLAXAoKdeEDiWlpDzET52vprLKYKHz49VnnNjii3nFwtweELJ%2F0D0Dxk1HEHHlI%2BuO8JXfObnVBVnqLHZ85ziWn4Z88RemSSfQNDMXeE47zV9bwkISRcYX6jd9iwIrPbsKY0miRKxxWkHpxizA1QM2XVP8X19yuD8%2F2kABevyS5LCyKdurBAF1gMSdpg2S7dAZgUbP27GZLoTO9PbYVoc0HQtqp95V7X7S94DtFnBhNwI6zwtJ8PyREJAiKdhZipY%2BvHfU8bt%2FfmwND98QDVYuuEwrbOgHj%2FSOy0puRnMTAm8M0D%2Fk6L9GJu11OtoPG7XeITjqZl3DkTJcxXbPak1U9dBr%2BqgC%2FORDPGPb4vapqHF2VaQNhhAl71lhhnx1gHclwak5iNXMEyT50MJ4MsJJTvruSeXu8u0zx3VTdFAwq2A%2BDlda4DkJ6DA0qxOBXDnVd%2BQF2i3dRcpvTM0TxLvLNJHi8JTBImok3iTS3K4oZmJd4aTILuvolWwFs2fu2z%2BiGz9AfAor9CI3m1ifyaOfnSiNFrw%2Boj0H1FKGapD%2Bxtg0MLz22KYGOrEBGeM8lMfz4alsNTBtsEgX2aPmDgVcttBC%2Fkwj%2FNk43jSjorAvxQZaq3PNjz%2FT5Py5LmlEoFMHh9bG1U%2FQpms1baz4xras1RXJdh%2BKMPKcgmyo%2BZGDnMVqgzZea2EIzbaq1UlGrOuWGfzSklc%2FyEM8x1luPhstvDoNukiMPfb9ueT%2Fp7Rd3jp20bBM7QHetxDP14sJle5MdFM3XjrFq7T06rq33C%2BqJ7ZqKZliTWsDoUIe&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230811T143544Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYYPBZCJEN%2F20230811%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=8efee295a6e5df2aca1d34a543109a20a899ea8e97aa50675b692f9c8ebe7768&hash=1659fa0d048b36c63023dc0b3026ec6cb4484869d05aeb3c2bc37971ddf02c88&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S002437950100578X&tid=spdf-9d25a92d-2a42-48a2-bba3-785b8866cbb2&sid=7b481755277b5747fa1ba61761c29962b744gxrqb&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=110f5807545656510603&rr=7f5134ee0ba41100&cc=th)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question? Which two conditions? For some proposition $P$ (your "two conditions") to be necessary for "$\phi(N)$ and $N$ are similar", there needs to be an implication from this to $P$. Which exactly is your question: (1) "$\phi(N)$ similar to $N$" implies $P$" or (2) "$\phi(N)$ and $N$ similar, and $N$ nilpotent" implies $P$", or (3) "$\phi(N)$ and $N$ similar, and $N$ that specific nilpotent" implies $P$" ?

Comment: My apology if I'm asking unclearly. I meant, how could it state that "Since $\phi$ preserves the characteristic polynomial and rank, \phi(N) must be similar to $N$"? Is it true that only two informations (preserving the characteristic polynomial and rank) imply that $\phi(N)$ must be similar to $N$ for N as defined above?

Comment: I see. Yes. Note that the characteristic polynomial of $N$ is $x^n$. If that is also the one of $\phi(N)$, then $\phi(N)$ is nilpotent too. Now, $\phi(N)$ is similar to its Jordan canonical form. For it being nilpotent this will have zeros on the main diagonal and some $1$s in the diagonal above it. The number of those $1$s is the rank. Since the rank is the same as $N$, the number of $1$s is $n-1$ . So, the Jordan form of $\phi(N)$ is $N$.

Comment: Thank you, you explained it clearly!